# Are questions about configuring 3rd party Joomla extensions 'on-topic'?

Tags: discussion, extensions

If we are using a 3rd party Joomla extension and would like to post questions regarding the proper configuration of that 3rd party extension, is that considered 'on-topic' for the Joomla StackExchage Site?

In asking this question, it is a 'given' that

- 3rd Party Extensions have their own support platforms

However, for numerous reasons, people may prefer to use the Joomla StackExchange site, while others in the Joomla community may benefit from seeing extension specific questions discussed on JSE.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and consideration of this question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this a lot and the first question I always ask is, have they read the extension documentation or contacted the support team.

In my opinion, if they:

- have read the extension documentation and cannot find the answer, **or**
- have contacted the support team and have not received a reply, **or**
- cannot find any similar questions, that have answers, on the StackExchange network

then it's ok to ask.